# Analysis of limit of $\sin(1/x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

[image: Image for reference]

I was reading about discontinuous functions when I came across this function.
It was stated that the function has no limiting value at $0$ since it rapidly oscillated between $[-1, 1]$ as we approached $0$.

My question is, thinking graphically, as we approach close to $0$ the inclination of the graph should be almost $90$ degrees ACW since the rate of oscillation increases exponentially as we move toward $0$ which means the graph can appear to pass through the origin (since it is an odd function; although it is undefined at origin) which should mean the limit is $0$.

Where am I going wrong with this intuition?

Edit: Added a drawing for more clarity on my question
[image]

Comment: It is not defined at 0 however you can construct a sequence which takes your favourite value arrbitrarily close to zero

Comment: Can you reconcile your intuition with the fact that no matter how small you choose $x>0$, there are still infinitely many $0<y<x$ such that $\sin(1/y)=1$ and infinitely many $0<z<x$ such that $\sin(1/z)=-1$?

Comment: For more fun, look at the graphs of [$y = \sin\left(\frac{1}{\sin (1/x)}\right)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%281%2F%28sin%281%2Fx%29%29%29+from+x%3D0.02+to+0.35) and [$y = \sin\left(\frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sin (1/x)}\right)}\right)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%281%2F%28sin%281%2F%28sin%281%2Fx%29%29%29%29%29+from+x%3D0.05+to+0.18). For the last one you'll probably have to rely mostly on what you know happens, because most of the details can't be shown graphically, unless done in a very schematic way.

Comment: Where you go wrong is at the very end, with the words "...which should mean the limit is $0$." It simply _doesn't_ mean that. If you want an actual explanation of where your thoughts are going wrong you need to tell us _why_ it seems that way to you - as long as your point is that it just seems that way there's not much to be said

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich It seems like the graph tends to 0 from both sides, so I got that

Comment: Huh? Once again, saying "It seems that..." is not going to help! You need to say _why_ it seems that way. Because that's only the way it seems _to you_ - to all the rest of us it's obvious from the graph that the function does _not_ tend to zero from either side.

Comment: I determined that from the fact that sin(1/x) is odd function; I am referring to the image I have inserted with the edit

Comment: @user3733558 By small in calculus, don't we take an infinitesimally small number; or is this also due to the fact that the rate of oscillations is also extremely large. In such a case how do we determine which one is larger? If I had to take a small number I can also take a number such that the given function can be plotted right? What am I missing

Comment: @Draculin: I didn't simply say "small", I said "no matter how small". And to answer your question "I can also take a number such that the given function can be plotted right?", it's precisely the point I'm trying to guide you to: actually no, you can't.
A different approach to convince yourself: substitute $x=1/t$, then $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \sin(1/x)$ is equivalent to $\lim_{t \to +\infty} \sin(t)$, if it exists. What does this tell you?

Comment: @Draculin, a last argument: let's assume that you actually could "zoom in" like you've shown in your picture. The curve is vertical, which means the derivative must tend to either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. Importantly, that's one or the other, right? The derivative is fairly easy to calculate: $\frac{-\cos(1/x)}{x^2}$. So what is the limit of that derivative as $x$ tends to $0$? Is it $+\infty$, $-\infty$ or is it in fact indeterminate? (hint: it's the last one)

Comment: @user3733558 This was what I was looking for, thank you

Comment: To further extend what @user3733558 said, for each extended real number $r$ there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_n \rightarrow 0$ (even a one-sided such sequence) such that the limit of the difference quotients evaluated relative to $x=0$ and $x=x_n$ approaches $r$ (in fact, when $r$ is not infinite, the sequence can be chosen so that all the difference quotients are equal to $r).$ In the case that $r$ is finite, simply consider the intersections of $y = \sin(1/x)$ with the line $y = rx$ to come up with the desired sequence $\{x_n\}.$

Answer (score 1):

The rate of the oscillation does indeed "blow up" around $x=0$. What this means is that there are infinitely many waves in the interval $(-\delta,\delta)$ for any positive $\delta$, and in each of these waves you can find $y$-values of between $-1$ and $1$. Since the $y$-values don't settle upon a single value, the limit does not exist. Try comparing the behaviour of $\sin(1/x)$ around $x=0$ with $x\sin(1/x)$.